# Разобрать строку на части

Tags: php, строки, синтаксический-анализ

Есть переменная:

```
$ text = 'Тут строка текста в которой могут быть и цифры';
```

Нужно вывести только те слова, которые имеют не менее 3 знаков и поместить каждое слово между тегом strong. Цифры выводим, как есть (любое кол-во символов). Знаки препинания не выводим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если всё правильно понял, то попробуйте так:

```
$pattern = array('/\b\D{1,2}\b/iu', '/\b\w{3,}|\d+\b/iu', '/\s+/');
$replace = array(' ', '<strong>$0</strong>', ' '); 
echo preg_filter($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

или так:

```
$words = preg_split('/(\b\D{1,2}\b)|\s/iu', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$wrapped = array_map(
   function ($el) {
      return '<strong>'.$el.'</strong>';
   },
   $words
);
echo implode(' ', $wrapped);
```

Comment: Точно! Спасибо большое, Deonis) Чет класс не дает поставить)